# Writing a text file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I am using VB.NET and [SQL Server 2005](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2005), and I want to write a text file from the database like.

Open a text file, read the data from the database then write into the text file.

Code.

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name, Dept from table", con)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

While dr.Read()

    Dim data As String
    data = File.ReadAllText(dr.Item("PersonID"))
    File.WriteAllText("D:\test.txt", data)
End While
```

The above code is showing error, How to write a text file

VB.NET Code Help

Comment: Well, what is the error?

Comment: @Sosh ReadAllText takes a Path, not data! it reads a File Path... even if PersonID is something like C:\myfile.txt the file at D: will only contain the last read file, as WriteAllText overwrites it (creating always a new file)! and can't you see the massive amount of time here?

Comment: @balexandre - I'm not the one asking for an answer.  Also not sure I understand your point about time.  My point was that if you post a question about a problem that includes an error, **you should of course also post the error.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code you are not actually reading from the database. Try this:

```
Using writer = New StreamWriter("d:\test.txt")
    While dr.Read()
        Dim id = dr.GetInt32(0)
        Dim name = dr.GetString(1)
        Dim dept = dr.GetString(2)

        writer.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", id, name, dept))
    End While
End Using
```

Comment: if you use a TimeSpan to see how long StreamWrite uses, File.WriteAllLines is extremely faster than StreamWriter!

Comment: I have 20 lines that read a file, get it's content size, and write the file again with the size in, and using StreamRead and StreamWriter it took around 28 ms, with File.ReadAllLines and File.WriteAllLines now takes 3 ms !!

Comment: @balexandre what if the SQL query returns millions of records? You are going to load all of them into memory?

Comment: in my case, I'm working with 1800 lines of text, the times I gave u are for that. regarding "1 million" I would probably need to make calculations, but in a Windows environment, YES I would use memory!

Answer (score 1):

```
cmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT ID, Name, Dept from table", con)
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

Dim sb as new StringBuilder

While dr.Read()

    ''Let's read line by line and Append it to our StringBuilder
    sb.AppendLine(
           String.Format("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}", 
                   dr.item("ID"), dr.item("Name"), dr.item("Dept") ))

End While

''Now that we have all data in our StringBuilder, lets put into our file

File.WriteAllLines("D:\test.txt", sb.ToString())
```

**P.S**. from a C# guy ... please verify if the code it right :) (C# code below)

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my Connection String"))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT ID, Name, Dept from table";

        con.Open();
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        while (dr.Read())
            // Let's read line by line and Append it to our StringBuilder
            sb.AppendLine(
                String.Format("{0} | {1} | {2} | {3}",
                    dr["ID"], dr["Name"], dr["Dept"]));

        // Now that we have all data in our StringBuilder, lets put into our file
        File.WriteAllLines("D:\test.txt", sb.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`File.ReadAllText` if for reading *from* the file.

`File.WriteAllText` will write everything to the file, overwriting what is in it.

You need to get the data like this:

```
data = dr.Item("PersonID").ToString()
```

When writing, you probably want to [append the text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.appendalltext.aspx) to it:

```
File.AppendAllText("D:\test.txt", data);
```

What would be slightly more efficient would be to loop through you data, building the whole set of data in memory (adding line breaks at the end of each row) and then writing it all in one go with `File.WriteAllText`. I am assuming the amounts of data are not massive, as this approach will be using more memory but will cause less disk IO.